# Polynomial divisibility of a minimum polynomial

Tags: polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

I am considering $x^2-x-1$ over $F=\mathbb{Z}/2=\{0,1\}$ as the minimum polynomial of a $3\times 3$ matrix $A$ with entries from $F$.

I know that the characteristic polynomial (in this case a degree 3 polynomial) is supposed to be able to divide some power of the minimum polynomial, but I have come across the statement that no power of $x^2-x-1$ is divisible by any polynomial of degree 3 over $F$ with no proof or hint.

Is this an obvious result and I am just being dense? How would one go about proving a statement like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $F$ is a field, $F[x]$ is a UFD.  Suppose a polynomial of degree 3, $p(x)$ divides $(x^2-x-1)^n$ for some $n\geq 1$.  Then $$p(x)k(x) = (x^2-x-1)^n$$ for some $k(x)$.  However, the only factor of the right-hand side is $x^2-x-1$, so this can be the only factor of the left-hand side.  In particular, if x^2-x-1 divides $p(x)$, then the remainder would be a linear polynomial, which gives a contradiction.

Note: The minimal polynomial divides the characteristic polynomial, not the other way around.

Comment: One may add the minimal and characteristic polynomials have the same irreducible factors.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I understand that the minimum polynomial must share the roots of the characteristic polynomial and so the minimum polynomial must divide the characteristic polynomial. However there is always some power of the minimum polynomial for which the characteristic polynomial will divide the minimum polynomial raised to that power. I am trying to find the similarity classes of $3\times 3$ matrices that satisfy $A^6=I$, so I am looking at all possible combinations of factors of $x^6-1$ as possibilities. This particular one is impossible.